# Looking for a home page carousel

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation

I'm looking for a plug in for a carousel similar to this one http://www.worldrowing.com/

Essentially it's a carousel with a navigation to the side.  When you scroll over the navigation the carousel changes.

It's important that the content of the carousel (nav, images and text over the images) is editable within WordPress by editors, and not only editable by a programmer.

I haven't been able to find anything similar to this.  Has anyone got any pointers?

Comment: Without a doubt: [http://slidesjs.com/](http://slidesjs.com/)

Comment: This question "*will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion*".

Comment: I do like this but it doesn't give navigation options like the one in my example.  Any other recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my personal experience, the best WP Carousel/Slider I have seen and used was Nivo Slider. It's in the WordPress Extend Directory: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-nivo-slider/

Comment: I do like this but it doesn't give navigation options like the one in my example.  Any other recommendations?